# How do I get a Null value to validate in a serializers.DateTimeField() field?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework to validate JSON passed to a URL which acts as a webhook. Below is the JSON I'm passing and the Serializer used to validate the data. Is there any way I can get the serializers.DateTimeField() field to allow null values? I've marked the relevant fields below...

JSON passed to webhook:

```
{
    "type": "transaction.created",
    "data": {
        "account_id": "acc_00008gju41AHyfLUzBUk8A",
        "amount": -350,
        "created": "2015-09-04T14:28:40Z",
        "currency": "GBP",
        "description": "Ozone Coffee Roasters",
        "id": "tx_00008zjky19HyFLAzlUk7t",
        "category": "eating_out",
        "is_load": false,
        "settled": null, <-- this field is sometimes null
        "merchant": {
            "address": {
                "address": "98 Southgate Road",
                "city": "London",
                "country": "GB",
                "latitude": 51.54151,
                "longitude": -0.08482400000002599,
                "postcode": "N1 3JD",
                "region": "Greater London"
            },
            "created": "2015-08-22T12:20:18Z",
            "group_id": "grp_00008zIcpbBOaAr7TTP3sv",
            "id": "merch_00008zIcpbAKe8shBxXUtl",
            "logo": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/527043602623389696/68_SgUWJ.jpeg",
            "emoji": "",
            "name": "The De Beauvoir Deli Co.",
            "category": "eating_out"
        }
    }
}
```

Serializers.py:

```
class MerchantSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
    logo = serializers.URLField(max_length=250, required=False)

class DataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    account_id = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    amount = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()
    currency = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=3)
    description = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=250)
    id = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    category = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
    is_load = serializers.BooleanField()
    settled = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False) # <-- fails validation here
    merchant = MerchantSerializer()

class TransactionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    type = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    data = DataSerializer()
```

Comment: You probably need to add `allow_blank=True`?

Comment: you can use allow_null=True, if you do list the field, you will also need to use required=False for the case if the call skip the DateTimeField varaible

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add required=False in the field.

Serializer fields are required by default, hence you don't need to provide required=True for them. On the other hand, for optional fields you need to provide required=False.

As mentioned in the documentation:

> Normally an error will be raised if a field is not supplied during deserialization. Set to false if this field is not required to be present during deserialization.
>
> Setting this to False also allows the object attribute or dictionary key to be omitted from output when serializing the instance. If the key is not present it will simply not be included in the output representation.
>
> Defaults to True

Comment: while this might work for an omitted DateField, it would not work for an included DateField that has null, as the original poster asked. Django says: Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 2):

pretend that it's a char field:

```
birthday = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

This might be late but can be useful for other people who end up here for the solution. You actually need to `allow_null=True` to accept blank value and null value respectively.

```
settled = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False, allow_null=True)
```

Comment: don't think you can put allow_blank for the serializers.DateTimeField, i am running on Django Restframwork 3.10.3, and it showed errors during runtime if put in allow_blank